# Mask raster with second, categorical raster in python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have two rasters. One is a "normal" Sentinel-2 L1C and the other one is a categorical raster with levels from 0-5. They are both of the same extent. Is there any way to set pixels to NA that are of a specific level in the other raster without doing some kind of polygonization? 
No asking for any specific solution, but more for ideas;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I like @Johan use of raw GDAL, you can also do this with xarray:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

s2_fname = "..."
lc_fname = "..."
ignore_classes = [4, 5] # Say
s2 = xr.open_rasterio(s2_fname, chunks={"x":1024, "y":1024})
lc = xr.open_rasterio(lc_fname, chunks={"x":1024, "y":1024})
for my_class in ignore_classes:
    s2 = s2.where(lc != my_class, other=np.nan)
```

`s2` is similar to a numpy array, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Example using gdal in python:

```py
import gdal
ignore_category = 5 # example
se2fn = '/path/to/sentinel2/image.tif'
categoriesfn = '/path/to/categories/raster.tif'

ds = gdal.Open(se2fn , 1) # open SE2 image in edit mode
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
data = ds.ReadAsArray() # this may consume a lot of RAM
ds2 = gdal.Open(categoryfn)
categories = ds2.ReadAsArray()
ndval = band.GetNoDataValue()

# if next line raises an exception, the arrays are of different sizes
assert data.shape == categories.shape 

#set data to nodatavalue of the image by indexing the categories with the ignore value
data[categories==ignore_category] = ndval

# write and close datasets
band.WriteArray(data)
ds.FlushCache()
band = None
ds = None
del data
del categories
ds2 = None
```

Comment: that looks great, thanks a lot!! I could theoretically also specify more than one ignore_category right?

Comment: yes you could: `data[(categories==ignore_category) | (categories==second_ignore_category)]`. If you have a list of items, you could iterate through the list and set each value separately to no data, or do something more clever with numpy.